# Nginx: bug using if in location, how do I rectify

Tags: nginx

I am using nginx in reverse proxy mode.  In my server section I have this code to set expire and cache control of my static files.

```
     location ~* ^.+\.(css|js|png|gif)$ {
         access_log off;
         expires max;
         add_header Cache-Control public;
         if (!-f $request_filename) {
           proxy_pass  http://localhost:82;
         }

     }
```

This is [quite obviously creating issues](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil).
Can someone help me correct this code to use `try_files` or `rewrite`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least 2 techniques.

### error_page

Before the introduction of `try_files` directive the common method was to intercept error code 404 and process the request with a named location, e.g.

```
location ~* \.(css|js|png|gif)$ {
  access_log off;
  expires max;
  add_header Cache-Control public;
  error_page 404 = @upstream;
}
```

### try_files

The equivalent using `try_files` would be

```
location ~* \.(css|js|png|gif)$ {
  access_log off;
  expires max;
  add_header Cache-Control public;
  try_files $uri @upstream;
}
```

And the named location is the same for both scenarios:

```
location @upstream {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:82;
}
```

Comment: I completely agree, that using `error_page` seems like a hack, but in fact it is very powerful instrument. This particular use case is so frequent, that Nginx author decided to introduce `try_files`.