# Serve static files using Nginx but also proxy_pass to Node.js?

Tags: node.js, wiki

I’m hosting a Node.js Wiki server (openKB) on `/wiki` behind an Nginx server. How can I proxy_pass from Nginx while also having Nginx serve static assets hosted at `/wiki/public` and `/wiki/images` and `/wiki/stylesheets/build` and so on.

What I had tried but did not work:

```
location /wiki {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4444;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

EDIT:

Site: [dffrnt.com/wiki](http://dffrnt.com/wiki)

Output:
[image]
While the app runs just fine, the static assets are not getting served at all. I noticed some of the assets are 404 while some others are 503.

Here’s what’s on the server...

[image]

Comment: Please clarify the exact URLs and respective file system paths in your question. Please also clarify "did not work". What exactly you expected to happen and what happened instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nginx: bug using if in location, how do I rectify](http://serverfault.com/questions/282485/nginx-bug-using-if-in-location-how-do-i-rectify)

Comment: @TeroKilkanen thank you for your patience, I hope the details I have added are useful to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Try swapping the two locations

Comment: @ChristopherPerrin I think the second location was a mistake on my part, it served no purpose in the final app, I have removed it now. Thanks for turning my attention onto it.

Comment: Why don't you add a location for the longer path (possibly before the /wiki location)?